# gradle: dependencies are not being built first which give a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: gradle

I'm try to convert a maven project into gradle via 'gradle init' and googling the errors after doing a '**gradlew clean jar -x test**'.  I'm stumped on the latest error.  The problem seems like a dependency order where BasicTypeHelper is not being built first.

```
$ ./gradlew clean jar -x test
[...]

> Task :exec-parent:vector:compileJava FAILED
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/record/MaterializedField.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.BasicTypeHelper;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class BasicTypeHelper
  location: package org.apache.drill.exec.expr
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/vector/complex/reader/FieldReader.java:20: error: package org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader does not exist
import org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader.ListReader;
                                                             ^
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/vector/complex/reader/FieldReader.java:21: error: package org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader does not exist
import org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader.MapReader;
                                                             ^
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/vector/complex/reader/FieldReader.java:22: error: package org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader does not exist
import org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader.RepeatedListReader;
                                                             ^
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/vector/complex/reader/FieldReader.java:23: error: package org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader does not exist
import org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader.RepeatedMapReader;
                                                             ^
/home/hudson/workarea/drill/exec/vector/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/vector/complex/reader/FieldReader.java:24: error: package org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader does not exist
import org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.reader.BaseReader.ScalarReader;
[...]
```

The build.gradle file in the drill/exec/vector directory is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'antlr'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

group = 'org.apache.drill.exec'
description = 'exec/Vectors'
dependencies {
  antlr "org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2" // use ANTLR version 3

  compile project(':drill-protocol')
  compile project(':drill-common')
  compile project(':exec-parent:memory-parent:drill-memory-base')
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.9'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.7.9'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.7.9.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version:'2.5.0'
    compile group: 'com.carrotsearch', name: 'hppc', version:'0.7.1'
    compileOnly(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version:'2.7.1') {
exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
exclude(module: 'servlet-api-2.5')
exclude(module: 'servlet-api-2.5')
exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
exclude(module: 'jetty-util')
exclude(module: 'hadoop-yarn-api')
exclude(module: 'jets3t')
exclude(module: 'log4j')
exclude(module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
exclude(module: 'mockito-all')
exclude(module: 'commons-logging-api')
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
exclude(module: 'jersey-core')
exclude(module: 'jersey-server')
exclude(module: 'jersey-json')
exclude(module: 'jersey-client')
exclude(module: 'core')
exclude(module: 'jackson-core-asl')
exclude(module: 'jackson-mapper-asl')
exclude(module: 'jackson-xc')
exclude(module: 'jackson-jaxrs')
exclude(module: 'netty')
    }
}

task packageTests(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.test.output
  classifier = 'tests'
}
artifacts.archives packageTests

$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-05 13:22:49 UTC
Revision:     37007e1c012001ff09973e0bd095139239ecd3b3

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-32-generic amd64
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but there is a directory that is expected to already be built by a dependency and it isn't there. Did you solve your problem with build order?

Comment: Any updates ??? I'm having similar issue with gradle 4.10.2

Comment: Unfortunately, no response/solution/recommendation has been given.

Comment: I spent many hours, tried cleaning caches, changes versions, decompile dependency and check... But nothing helped. At the end i have been renaming my class and it started work. Stupid decision but it helped me. **PS**. if i rename  back the build again start failing.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with gradle 5.5.1